# Javascript: Find text (like ctrl+f) and return boolean if found

Tags: javascript, search, text, find, tampermonkey

Can anyone help me out with a function in javascript which is for searching a site for words (like the ctrl+f function of browsers) and return a bolean if found?

For example on this site it would like this:
searchText("Question");
It would search and find it on the top right and would return true.

Thanks already!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is `window.find()` method doing exactly what you want. It finds a string in window:

```
if (find(stringToFind)) {
    alert('Found');
}
```

Found string will also be highlighted. This function is supported in all major browsers (IE7+).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.find

Comment: If I would want to search for "Question" on this site would it look like this:
if (find("Question")) {
    alert('Found');
}

Also I am using Tampermonkey to run javascript

Comment: Yes, it would look like you posted. I don't know what Tampermonkey is :(

Comment: It is an addon for opera to run javascript :D
So we both learned something :>

Comment: It seems like this goes by the source code and it doesn't work for javascript changed source code.
Do you know any addon to "fix" this? Like Firebug?

Comment: Or is there a way to search for a javascript changed source code.
For example here for "Next text!": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390832/javascript-innerhtml-does-not-change-content-on-source-code

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery you can do:

```
if ( $('body').text().search('YOUR TEXT') == -1)
    return false;
else 
    return true;
```

Comment: I am pretty much a beginner :D What is jquery?

Comment: JQuery is a JavaScript based library , you can read more here : http://jquery.com/